# Using a Python dict to replace/clean data in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe(table2) that looks something like

```
57                  INVERNESS
361                 INVERNESS
533                 INVERNESS
535     INVERNESS KERRY DOWNS
758           INVERNESS GREEN
807                 INVERNESS
970           INVERNESS POINT
971                 INVERNESS
```

And so on..

And I need to map/replace the names using a Dict, (which I have in a Excel sheet)
When I read the translate table into Pandas I get a DF that looks like

```
             NSUBDIVISION
SUBDIVISION 
*HUFFMAN**8MILES NE  OTHER
0                    OTHER
00                   OTHER
000                  OTHER
INVERNESS POINT      INVERNESS
```

And so on..
When I convert it to a DICT using xlate=df.to_dict() I get a dict(xlate) that looks like:

```
{u'NSUBDIVISION': {u'*HUFFMAN**8MILES NE': u'OTHER',
  u'0': u'OTHER',
  u'00': u'OTHER',
  u'000': u'OTHER',
  u'0000': u'OTHER',
  u'INVERNESS POINT': u'INVERNESS',
```

And so ..on (I mention this as I'm not sure the dict is Properly formed)

I want to do something like

```
 table2['SUBDIVISION'].replace(to_replace=xlate,inplace=True)
```

I want to look up values in the 1st col of the xlate table match them to table2['SUBDIVISION'] and if found replace contents of SUBDIVISION with the values in xlate column 2 if not leave them alone (bonus..actually if col 2 is NAn I'd like to leave it alone as well)  for instance above finding INVERNESS POINT will be replaced by INVERNESS

currently I just get TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to create a [dictionary from the *Series*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) (rather than the DataFrame):

```
In [11]: translate_df['NSUBDIVISION'].to_dict()
Out[11]:
{'*HUFFMAN**8MILES NE': 'OTHER',
 '0': 'OTHER',
 '00': 'OTHER',
 '000': 'OTHER',
 'INVERNESS POINT': 'INVERNESS'}
```

And use this to [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) the column:

```
In [12]: df['SUBDIVISION'].replace(translate_df['NSUBDIVISION'].to_dict())
Out[12]:
0                INVERNESS
1                INVERNESS
2                INVERNESS
3    INVERNESS KERRY DOWNS
4          INVERNESS GREEN
5                INVERNESS
6                INVERNESS
7                INVERNESS
Name: SUBDIVISION, dtype: object
```

Comment: mmm I think the to dict helps,, but I have and need a DF as the final result and in any event after I got a good Dict using your suggestion I then ran table2['SUBDIVISION'].replace(xlate['NSUBDIVISION'].to_dict()) and got Key error on NSBDIVISION ??? The actual tables are much larger than the samples..   Nsubdivision (col2) is not unique, but the 1st column is which in the original df For Xlate is 'SUBDIVISION' ?

Comment: Ahh I had tried to reassign the translate dict to a new variable which it did not like..so it seems to have replaced but not "inplace" on the DF?

Comment: @dartdog a little confused with what you are doing tbh, don't think you should reuse xlate dictionary at all :s If there are multiple columns perhaps use iloc to access them...?

Comment: @dartdog adding as inplace, like in your example, changes df. :)

Comment: Odd this does not seem to do it?? (no errors though) >> table2['SUBDIVISION'].replace(df['NSUBDIVISION'],inplace=True)

Comment: This does the trick But I don't understand why the to_dict is required?  table2['SUBDIVISION'].replace(df['NSUBDIVISION'].to_dict(),inplace=True)

Comment: Nope,, it does not work without the to_dict ?? You may want to update the answer for completeness? to mark correct?

Comment: aargh! I thought I had tested that, now I *am* confused! tbh I think it *should*... could be a bug